# What is Probability that Stromville Sluggers will win?

Tags: probability

Need help solving the following problem:
The probability that the Stormville Sluggers will win a baseball game is 2/3.
Determine the probability to the *nearest thousandth*, that the Stromville Sluggers will win at least 6 of their next 8 games.

Comment: do you know about Bernoulli trials?

Comment: what do you know of the binomial theorem?

Comment: I expect this goes beyond the intent of the question, but it's worth noting that to answer the question you have to imagine that the assumption means that each game they play is independent and identically distributed.  That's not stated in the question.  Suppose, say, that they lost every third game but won all the others.  Then it would be true that the probability of winning a random game was $\frac 23$ but now the answer would depend on where in the cycle we were.  Realistically, independence and identical distribution are not very plausible assumptions.

Comment: @lulu "I expect this goes beyond the intent of the question". You know what, I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your question should show what you have tried and why that is not
good enough. Also ideally, comments should be on target and helpful. Here
is a guide toward the solution that I hope is helpful.

Let $X$ be the number of games won out of the next $n = 8$ games.
Subject to the assumptions mentioned in the *useful* Comment by @lulu,
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 8, p = 2/3)$ and 
$$P(X = k) = {8 \choose k}(2/3)^k (1/3)^{n-k},$$ for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 8.$

You seek $P(X \ge 6) = 1 - P(X \le 5) = P(X = 6) + P(X = 7) + P(X = 8).$

In R statistical software the answer can be found as shown below. You should
use the formula above and a calculator to get the answer so you will understand
how to use the general form of it (in your text) for the next binomial problem you encounter.

*Notes:* (a) The formula displayed above is for the binomial PDF of $X$ (or PMF, depending on your text). (b) Some
textbooks have a limited selection of CDF values in an Appendix, but my
guess is that the purpose of the problem is to familiarize you with the PDF
formula.
(c) The 'binomial theorem' is something else, not directly applicable here.

```
k = 6:8;  sum(dbinom(k, 8, 2/3))  # 'dbinom' is the PDF
## 0.4682213
1 - pbinom(5, 8, 2/3)             # 'pbinom' is the CDF
## 0.4682213
```

The plot below shows the PDF of $X$. The probability you seek is the sum
of the heights of the three thick red bars.

[image]

The probability $P(X = 0) =  (1/3)^8 = 0.00015$ is too small to show within
the resolution of this graph.